# Text goes below picture

Tags: html, css

I am creating the layout for a comment. However, the text goes underneath the image, and I can't seem to get rid of that.

Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fag55La3/1/) demonstrating the issue.

```css
.comments {
  padding: 10px;
}
.comments .comment {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.comments .comment .profile-picture {
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: inline-block;
}
.comments .comment .text-block {
  display: inline;
}
.timeago {
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<div class="comments">

 <div class="comment">

  <div class="profile-picture">
   <img src="http://fakeimg.pl/50x50/" />
  </div>

  <div class="text-block">
   <a href="#">
    Barack Obama
   </a>

   Change will not come if we wait for some other person or some other time. We are the ones we've been waiting for. We are the change that we seek.

   <br />

   <div class="timeago">20 hours ago</div>

  </div>

  <hr />

  <div class="clear"></div>

 </div>

 <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

How can I get the text to *not* go underneath the image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the display of both divs to table-cell

```
.comments .comment .profile-picture, .comments .comment .text-block{
    display:table-cell
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/fag55La3/4/)**

Answer (score 3):

You should use display: inline-block.
After that you should give text-block a certain width in which isn't bigger than 100% - image width (plus margin).

```
.comments .comment .profile-picture {
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: inline-block;
}
.comments .comment .text-block {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
   width: calc(100% - 60px);
}
```

Comment: This is a good solution - using floats is often unnecessary and it can bite you back some time later :)

Comment: Note: `width: calc(100% - 50px)` won't work because the parent div has a font-size bigger than 0px. For some reason CSS always add some margin between child divs.

Comment: Exactly the solution I had.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with clears and floats, I've updated your [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fag55La3/6/)

I've added this to your code:

```
.comments .comment .profile-picture {
  clear: both;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
.comments .comment .text-block {
  clear: both;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ok, you can try this

```
.comments .comment .profile-picture {
  vertical-align: top;
  display: inline-block;
}
.comments .comment .text-block {
  display: inline-block;
  width: calc(100% - 60px);
}
```

you can see it in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fag55La3/9/)

Answer (score 0):

Here I did 2 following things

1) Put float:left; here

```
.comments .comment .profile-picture {
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: inline-block;
     float:left;

}
```

2) Change display:inline to display:block;

```
.comments .comment .text-block {
  display: block;
}
```

It will work fine :)

Answer (score 0):

JSFIDDLE [here](http://jsfiddle.net/fag55La3/17/)

Edit CSS to look like this. I just floated image left and added some padding then. You don't even need to display text inline with this. Then clear: both; for the time.

```
.comments {
    padding: 10px;
}

.comments .comment {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

comments .comment .profile-picture {
    float:left;
    padding-right: 10px;
}

.timeago {
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    clear: both;
}
```